Docker container not loading .bashrc
This is a minified Dockerfile showing the problem:
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

ARG MINIFORGE_URL="https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-Linux-x86_64.sh"
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ARG USERNAME=nonroot
ARG GROUPNAME=${USERNAME}
ARG PORT=8000

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY ./environment.yml .
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y wget ca-certificates && \
    wget ${MINIFORGE_URL} -O Miniforge.sh && \
    bash Miniforge.sh -b -p /opt/miniforge3 && \
    PATH="$PATH:/opt/miniforge3/condabin" mamba env create -f environment.yml && \
    addgroup --gid $GID ${GROUPNAME} && \
    adduser --uid $UID --gid $GID --disabled-password --gecos "" ${USERNAME} && \
    chmod +x /entrypoint.sh && \
    mkdir -p /home/${USERNAME}/app && \
    su ${USERNAME} -s /bin/bash -c "PATH=/opt/miniforge3/condabin mamba init bash"

COPY --chown=${USERNAME}:${GROUPNAME} ./main.py /home/${USERNAME}/app/

USER ${USERNAME}
WORKDIR /home/${USERNAME}/app
ENV PORT=${PORT}
EXPOSE ${PORT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]

So the dockerfile just installs miniforge3 python distribution, creates an environment from the supplied environment.yml file, and copies a single main.py file into the WORKDIR.
The entrypoint just switches to the correct conda (mamba) environment and executes fastapi server (main.py is a minimal fastapi app example):
#!/bin/bash --login

set -e

cat /home/nonroot/.bashrc
env
conda init
mamba activate "$CONDA_ENV"
fastapi dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT} main.py

Despite the "cat" command i put in there confirms conda initialization code is in the user's .bashrc, and even the entrypoint script starts with "--login", running the container fails does not show any variables set in .bashrc when it executes "env", so mamba/fastapi execution fails with:
/entrypoint.sh: line 9: conda: command not found

Any clue?

The man page says "When  an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.". I'm a little unsure about what it means, but it might mean that .bashrc isn't run in login shells.

kind of confirmed this. if i run the container with -it it gives me a shell. it's bash but has no prompt, so obviously it's not a login shell. Still struggling with this.

And i tryied also changing entrypoint to [ "/bin/bash", "--login", "-c" ] and passing entrypoint.sh as CMD with the same results

why dont you source the conda.sh in you docker-entrypoint.sh ??

That works, as well as adding /opt/miniforge3/condabin dir to PATH in my entrypoint, i already tried those things. Thanks for the answer, but this is not a i want to make it work question, i want to understand why docker does not give me a login shell. Apparently if i run with --entrypoint /bin/bash and cmd --login from the cli it does, so i'm lost here.

Also, i'd rather not being dependant on installation paths, as those may change in future miniforge releases, etc

And of course i already tried manually source .bashrc at my entrypoint with no success, which is crazy

@roirodriguez A lot of .bashrcs shipped by distros contain a block that returns if the shell isn’t interactive. Which could explain why it doesn’t work even if you source it explicitly, and it is a clue that .bashrc isn’t meant for non-interactive use. Arguably, the ‘proper’ way is to modify $PATH. (The proper, proper way is for installers to install into common paths, but I guess Miniforge didn’t get the memo.)

@Biffen That's exactly the case. May you answer so i can mark it correct?

To quote Bash Startup Files from the GNU Bash Manual:

When Bash is invoked as [...] a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order....

This particular bash invocation is a non-interactive shell (you're running a script, not manually typing in commands) and .bashrc isn't in the list of files that it automatically reads.
In your script you can manually load .bashrc yourself.  (Your boilerplate shell dotfiles might do something similar.)
#!/bin/bash
[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && . "$HOME/.bashrc"
...

Remember that most paths to running things in Docker don't read shell dotfiles at all, which is why you need to do it manually here.  You might not run mamba init bash and instead do the same setup in the entrypoint script (see for example How does micromamba work and what is "condabin?")
#!/bin/sh
. /opt/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh
...


Comment from @Biffen above is the good one. At the start of default bashrc files for debian there's a line returning and doing nothing if noninteractive. If you read the same link you referenced, first subsection is titled "Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login". Note the OR with --login, which is my case. So .bashrc is loaded for noninteractive shells if --login is supplied.

The documentation doesn't seem to say that.  It only mentions .bashrc for interactive non-login shells (2nd section), but shell scripts aren't interactive (3rd section).  As I note at the last paragraph, in any case most Docker paths (RUN commands, docker run --entrypoint overrides) don't read any shell dotfiles at all, and I'd avoid relying on them.
